# How to implement src_key_padding_mask in a vision transformer

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model, vision-transformer

I am implementing a modified vision transformer based on the [Github implementation](https://github.com/jankrepl/mildlyoverfitted/blob/master/github_adventures/vision_transformer/custom.py). The author has also published a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/ovB0ddFtzzA) explaining the implementation. But this implementation doesn't have any provision to incorporate `src_key_padding_mask`. (The built-in transformer encoder accepts this as a parameter) I know that I have to perform some mathematical operation using this mask in the `forward` method of the `Attention` module. The mask contains `True` where there is a padding token and `False` elsewhere.

If I just place `dp = dp @ mask` just after the dot product of query and key, will it serve the purpose of `src_key_padding_mask` used in the built-in version?

```
dp = (q @ k_t) * self.scale # (n_samples, n_heads, n_patches + 1, n_patches + 1)
dp = dp @ mask
```